# WordPress function undefined when adding a shortcode

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

We would like to add a custom function of a `shortcode` in `wp_include/functions.php`.

This is the function:

```php
function url_id() {
 
    $apiUrl = 'https:exampleurl.api.com/exemple123';

    $response = wp_remote_get($apiUrl);

    return wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

}
add_shortcode('session_id', 'url_id');
```

But we were getting this error:

> **There has been a critical error on this website.
> Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.**

After reading some more troubleshooting documentation we added these two lines in `wp-config`:

```php
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

define( 'WP_CACHE', true );
```

And after that we are getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_shortcode() in /home/c1624672c/public_html/woo/wp-includes/functions.php:18 Stack trace: #0 /home/c1624672c/public_html/woo/wp-settings.php(111): require() #1 /home/c1624672c/public_html/woo/wp-config.php(104): require_once('/home/c1624672c...') #2 /home/c1624672c/public_html/woo/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/c1624672c...') #3 /home/c1624672c/public_html/woo/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/c1624672c...') #4 /home/c1624672c/public_html/woo/index.php(17): require('/home/c1624672c...') #5 {main} thrown in /home/c1624672c/public_html/woo/wp-includes/functions.php on line 18
>
> There has been a critical error on this website. Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom shortcodes to your website, that can be done via a custom plugin, or in your theme (as I suspect you're trying to do).

Instead of editing `wp-includes/functions.php`, add your code to `wp-content/themes/<name-of-your-theme>/functions.php`.

---

You should **never** edit the core files of WordPress, which includes all files in `/wp-admin` and `/wp-includes`. When you upgrade WordPress in the future, these files will be overwritten, and you'll lose any changes you've made.

The error message occurs because you're attempting to use the `add_shortcode()` function before WordPress has fully loaded, and defined all available functions.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the shortcode parameter session_id because session_id predefined function in wordpress see the blow or your code

```
add_shortcode('session_id', 'url_id');
```

But right code will be work when you change the session_id.